# Background Key Listener in Groovy or Java or any JVM language

Tags: java, groovy, keyboard-shortcuts

I wish to make a key listener that would run in the background of my computer that would always be listening no certain keys. I would like to do it in groovy and would somehow like to make a method that would act like this

```
def onClick(String key, Closure closure) {
   //TODO
}

onClick "CTRL+ALT+T", { /* do transformation of clipboard */ }
```

However, I'm not quite sure how to get this working in the background. I had success with the swing to do a task, but I had to obviously have it in the foreground, which meant clicking on it whenever I wanted to execute a shortcut.

Anyone know how this might be achieved in Groovy? Or any other JVM language? Thanks!

Comment: You can't with plain java. Java key listening can be done on focused java gui components, you cannot attach a listener to "the keyboard".

Comment: Do you have a good suggestion as to which scripting language I could do this in Windows then??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java key listener to track all keystrokes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177416/java-key-listener-to-track-all-keystrokes)