# how to record keystrokes in background using java?

Tags: java, background-process, keystroke

I am going to research on *which key typed most in which hour in a 24-hour-day?*
Later, I would research on *which word used most in which hour in a 24-hour-day?*

Say in the evening you would find most used word good or bye as people usually ends up their meeting in the evening.

So, I need to record keystrokes on the background using a `java` application with a time-stamp.
My questions are:

1. How to run a `java` program on the background?(Obviously informing the user).
2. How to record keystrokes which are used in other applications and counted in the `java` application without affecting its original application?

Note that:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177416/java-key-listener-to-track-all-keystrokes) question does not serve my problem. Though it has an accepted answer, but the answer is not helpful for me because **it could not distinguish between uppercase and lowercase letter, it returns same ASCII character**. It just gave some sources and some other files. I expect more readable answer and a **clear view how the java program launch on the start up and run on the background**.

Comment: You probably need to look at the [KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) class.

Comment: Maybe you should switch to C(++) an create hooks

Comment: sure, but KeyListener class works for working in the specific java application. Is there anyway to interact it with other OS dependent applications? @ChthonicProject

Comment: If you looking for something that works as a keylogger across multiple applications, then Java is probably not the right way to go. It may be doable, but I doubt it will be a simple task. I'm afraid I don't have enough expertise to comment further in this direction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java key listener to track all keystrokes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177416/java-key-listener-to-track-all-keystrokes)

Comment: I also think that java is not the right language for this work, but I am afraid of delaying the original work if I give more concentration on language. @ChthonicProject

Comment: but I have no idea about C(++) hooks! @user

Answer (score 1):

Just a little information to get you moving in the right direction. What you are looking to implement to listen for the keystrokes is KeyListener. I believe the actual function is keyTyped(ActionEvent e) but am not sure.

Other then that to run a program silently in the background will probably require some manipulation of the window + windows properties. You could just have the program run without a UI, or create a very lightweight UI that posts data. If you are looking for an actual "out of sight out of mind" background process, I am not sure how to do this with Java. However I imagine just an un-intrusive GUI would be sufficient for your purposes.