# JAVA Catch input without focus - Magnetic Strip Reader

Tags: java, keylistener, keyboard-events, keyboard-hook, magnetic-cards

I need to create a system which in background can listen to all data inputs from a MSR (Magnetic Strip Reader).

I have a GUI in my program but I **don't have the focus** on it because **another program simultaneously need to get the same data from the MSR**.

There is **no possibility** to have the users **creep two time** the card, and **neither** to **change the focus** from one program to another.

The only workaround is to listen in background for all the inputs I think.

- **How can I do that?**
- **There are already classes for that?**
- **There is a way to specifically listen only for MSR inputs?**

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java key listener to track all keystrokes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177416/java-key-listener-to-track-all-keystrokes)

Comment: Do you know how to identify exactly only the inputs from MSR?

Comment: I think that, if the MSR is just a UBS device, it is not trivial to determine which device genereted the key events. Maybe you need to have some sort of "driver" for the MSR.

Comment: [Alvaro Sanchez Martinez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13094502/alvaro-sanchez-martinez) left this link to [javaQuery](https://www.javaquery.com/2014/05/how-to-create-key-logger-in-java.html) about how to capture any input with Java while running in the background.

Comment: You can check my [lightweight library](https://github.com/Animeshz/keyboard-mouse-kt) for keyboard event listening and such purpose, check [the docs](https://animeshz.github.io/keyboard-mouse-kt/) for more info. Yet I haven't implement anything such to access the type of device or its id, but may implement if you request.