# Global KeyLogger

Tags: java, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keylogger

I have been searching for a while now for a library that allows me to know which Key-Event was pressed. But not in a focused program/text-field or anything else but as a process that runs in the background.
I'm not trying to write a keylogger but I want to create a program that lets me create shortcuts for key-combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using JNI and [Global System hook](http://kra.lc/blog/2011/07/java-global-system-hook/). Global System hook applies a `Key Logger` to the whole computer and not the JVM therefore allowing you to capture key presses outside of the JVM.

An example implementation of it can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12177785/4601149)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Java has native support for something like this. Java is really a language of abstraction, it gets you further away from the OS to make developing easier - but also for security purposes.

Key events are core to the OS so you will (likely) need a language or a library has that capability. Check out [JNativeHook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/).

Comment: I allready tried using that library but it failed due to the fact that the 32bit .dll didn't work with my 64bit system.