# How to stop the program when pressing a certain button on the keyboard, for example s

Tags: java

I am new to programming and at the moment I am doing a task, the essence of which is the emulation of scanning a person by gender and age with a further pass to a zone defined for its parameters. I was told to supplement the program so that, for example, when you press the S button on the keyboard, the program ends.
Please tell me how can I implement this. I have 4 classes in my code:

**main**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PassportScan passportScan = new PassportScan();
        Guard guard = new Guard();
        while (true) {
            Person person = passportScan.methodScan();
            String result = guard.checkPerson(person);
            System.out.println(result);
        }

    }
}
```

**PassportScan**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PassportScan {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Person methodScan() {
        System.out.println("Scanning gender");
        String gender = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Scanning age");
        int age = scanner.nextInt();
        return new Person(gender, age);

    }

}
```

**Person**

```
public class Person {
    private String gender;
    private Integer age;

    public Person(String gender, Integer age) {
        this.gender = gender;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

}
```

**Guard**

```
public class Guard {
    public String checkPerson(Person personToCheck) {
        String gender = personToCheck.getGender();
        int age = personToCheck.getAge();

        if (age < 18 && gender.equals("M")) {
            return "Zone 1";
        }
        if (age >= 18 && gender.equals("M")) {
            return "Zone 2";
        }
        if (age < 18 && gender.equals("F")) {
            return "Zone 3";
        }
        if (age >= 18 && gender.equals("F")) {
            return "Zone 4";
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the tip and your time!

Comment: First check in the PassportScan if the input is = s then
use the following code "System.exit(0);"

Comment: You can't detect an event in the command line environment. You should provide a GUI, and then you can use the KeyListener class to detect a keyboard event.
Alternatively, you can read commands from standard input and then execute a proper function.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there will be two scenario for this.

**1. **Once Press S****  >>> You want to terminate the program

Simply its not available in normal console
but there is way to achieve refer this post for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/1066647/8524713

**2. Press S and then press Enter key** >>
In this case its easy

check on each gender input if its S break the loop

try below code for reference

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PassportScan passportScan = new PassportScan();
        Guard guard = new Guard();
        while (true) {
            Person person = passportScan.methodScan();
            //checking if person object is null if ts null means s is enter
            // break from loop
            if(person==null) {
                break;
            }
            String result = guard.checkPerson(person);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
   static class PassportScan {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        public Person methodScan() {
            System.out.println("Scanning gender");
            String gender = scanner.next();

            //check if string input is S or s
            // then its returning null person object
            if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) return null;

            System.out.println("Scanning age");
            int age = scanner.nextInt();
            return new Person(gender, age);

        }

    }
```

one more way is to directly terminate in PassportScan class once S is typed

```
class PassportScan {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        public Person methodScan() {
            System.out.println("Scanning gender");
            String gender = scanner.next();

            //check if string input is S or s terminating prog
            if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) System.exit(0)

            System.out.println("Scanning age");
            int age = scanner.nextInt();
            return new Person(gender, age);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably have some `Component` in that you display something, for example a (`class` that extends) `JFrame`, lets call it `c`.

Now call:

```
c.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (Character.toLowerCase(e.getKeyChar()) == 's') System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
});
```

It is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37886212) to catch a `KeyEvent` without a GUI (When you think about it, how should Java know that the key was pressed in your application? If it would catch any `KeyEvent` on the device, you could easily build spyware that catches passwords or sth.)