# How to use hot keys with java app while it is running?

Tags: java, hotkeys

I made a console application on java. I want to stop it whenever and wherever I want using hot keys (ctrl+T for example). How can I implement such action?
I want to terminate it even if another window is opened without returning back to my app window.
If I can't do it using java, then what shell script should I use? I am on Windows.

Comment: This may help [how to run this key listener in background in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44502528/how-to-run-this-key-listener-in-background-in-java/44502826)

Comment: It's a console app, but I use awt (java.awt.Robot)