# How do I check in Java if a key is down in ANY context?

Tags: java, keyboard, java-native-interface, keyboard-events

I've looked at so many articles and they all show how to check key events with a framework like Swing.

How can I check for key pressing in any context, regardless of the program being focused or not. I've heard you can possibly use JNI to do this, but I have no idea where to start. If anyone has some insight, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Oh, you want to make a keylogger in Java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I write a key listener to track all keystrokes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177416/how-can-i-write-a-key-listener-to-track-all-keystrokes-in-java)

Comment: Yes! Thank you @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere! This is exactly what I'm looking for, I guess it's a matter of search terms.

Comment: Yeah it's funny I searched for 'java keylogger' in my search engine.

Comment: Funny, I got half a dozen hits on my first try with those keywords, include source code. Google is my friend.

Comment: Good for you, Google hates me. Not exactly sure what you mean. If you read any the post, you'd know that I'm not looking for Swing-type key events, and that's what those half a dozen hits are about.